# how to set currency value for textbox in c# Windows form

Tags: c#

During run time I want to insert some integer value on textbox it should be display like currency format

example : 1000000  is input
Expect 1,000,000.00

The below code is execute failure format

example 12345678
but actually i got  85,671,234  after first four(1234)integer the cursor automatically moved to backside

The code is

```
txtpurchasecost.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", double.Parse(txtpurchasecost.Text));
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtpurchasecost.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", double.Parse(txtpurchasecost.Text));
```

and you may also specify the culture manually for the separators:

```
txtpurchasecost.Text = string.Format(
  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), 
  "{0:N2}", 
  double.Parse(txtpurchasecost.Text));
```

Also you can check this article: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable  response but its not working after 4 integer value the cursor moved to back again

Comment: @BavyaAugus Then the problem is maybe with the textbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = 0;

if (int.TryParse(txtpurchasecost.Text, out temp))
{
    txtpurchasecost.Text = (int.Parse(txtpurchasecost.Text)).ToString("C2");
}
```

try this, this will fix your issue.